# Regex expression in Dart

Tags: regex, dart

I want to catch all of the cases that are exactly called `number` and then all of the cases where number is surrounded by underscores, for example `hey_number`, `number_hey` or `hey_number_hey`, the thing is that I don't want to catch cases like `hey_numbers` or `hey_numberrr`

I did end up with

```
(^number$)|(.*[_]{1}number.*)|(.*number[_]{1}.*)
```

but it still catches `hey_numbers`

Answer (score 2):

Applying this expression

```
(?:\w+_|\b)number(?:_\w+|\b)
```

on this text:

```
hey_number, number_hey or hey_number_hey, the thing is that I don't want to catch cases like hey_numbers or hey_numberrr or nnumber or nnumber_chesu
```

you get:

```
hey_number
number_hey
hey_number_hey
```

You can try it with [this tester](https://regex101.com/r/VCJK4s/1).